# Bash 'read' command. 'enter' key goes to the beginning of the line instead of completing 'read' command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, initramfs, getty

I used agetty ( v2.27 ) to create a bash shell terminal through ttyGS0. For some reason, when I used a computer to create a console via the ttyGS0 line, after I call `read`, pressing the Enter key goes to the beginning of the line instead of completing the 'read' command.

Ctrl+J completes the `read` command. The getty process is initialized inside the initramfs because of the work requirement. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: So when typically you use 'read' command, you type the input  and then press enter to store the variable. But on my shell, when I use read, after typing the input, press enter go to the beginning of the line instead of terminate 'read'.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you 'used a computer to create a console'?  What kind of terminal emulator did you use?

Comment: Normally enter sends carriage-return and this is translated to newline by the tty driver. run `stty -a` on the terminal. Check that flag `icrnl` does not have a `-` flag. But other flags matter too, so compare with another terminal that is working.

Comment: I use agetty to create a console on an embedded device. Then I connect to that console through a host computer using `screen`.

Comment: @meuh I check stty -a there is a minus in front of icrnl . I change the setting and it works! Thank you